# React native load data from json which stored in github

Tags: arrays, json, react-native, fetch

I have a json file. [Link here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mudassir21/server/master/newsCategory.json)

```js
{"Cat": [
 {"key": "a",
  "title": "Bangladesh",
  "image": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mudassir21/server/master/img/bangladesh.jpg",
  "news": [
   {"key": "a", "title": "ICC T20", "details": "rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr rhgiuhs huiwghf 3ejfow fnhbviuo rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9 gefgey8 egf8 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i 9ewhdf8 hwed7uhyeu ewhdfyuh"},
   {"key": "b", "title": "DITF 2018", "details": "rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr rhgiuhs huiwghf 3ejfow fnhbviuo rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy gefgey8 egf8 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i fhgiuh hguhsi ruhgiuherih shif"},
   {"key": "a", "title": "ICC T20", "details": "rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr rhgiuhs huiwghf 3ejfow fnhbviuo rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9 gefgey8 egf8 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i 9ewhdf8 hwed7uhyeu ewhdfyuh"},
   {"key": "b", "title": "DITF 2018", "details": "rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr rhgiuhs huiwghf 3ejfow fnhbviuo rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy gefgey8 egf8 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i fhgiuh hguhsi ruhgiuherih shif"},
   {"key": "a", "title": "ICC T20", "details": "rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr rhgiuhs huiwghf 3ejfow fnhbviuo rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9 gefgey8 egf8 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i 9ewhdf8 hwed7uhyeu ewhdfyuh"},
   {"key": "b", "title": "DITF 2018", "details": "rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr rhgiuhs huiwghf 3ejfow fnhbviuo rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy gefgey8 egf8 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i fhgiuh hguhsi ruhgiuherih shif"},
   {"key": "a", "title": "ICC T20", "details": "rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr rhgiuhs huiwghf 3ejfow fnhbviuo rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9 gefgey8 egf8 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i 9ewhdf8 hwed7uhyeu ewhdfyuh"},
   {"key": "b", "title": "DITF 2018", "details": "rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr rhgiuhs huiwghf 3ejfow fnhbviuo rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy gefgey8 egf8 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i fhgiuh hguhsi ruhgiuherih shif"},
   {"key": "a", "title": "ICC T20", "details": "rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr rhgiuhs huiwghf 3ejfow fnhbviuo rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9 gefgey8 egf8 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i 9ewhdf8 hwed7uhyeu ewhdfyuh"},
   {"key": "b", "title": "DITF 2018", "details": "rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr rhgiuhs huiwghf 3ejfow fnhbviuo rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy gefgey8 egf8 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i fhgiuh hguhsi ruhgiuherih shif"}
         ]
 },
 {"key": "b",
  "title": "Sports",
  "image": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mudassir21/server/master/img/sports.jpg",
  "news": [
   {"key": "a", "title": "BD vs IND", "details": "rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy gefgey8 egf8 rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr fhiuerhngf 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i 9ewhdf8 hwed7uhyeu ewhdfyuh"},
   {"key": "b", "title": "ICC Cricket World Cup", "details": "rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr rhgiuhs rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy gefgey8 egf8 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i 9ewhdf huiwghf 3ejfow fnhbviuo fhgiuh hguhsi ruhgiuherih shif"},
   {"key": "a", "title": "ICC T20", "details": "rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr rhgiuhs huiwghf 3ejfow fnhbviuo rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9 gefgey8 egf8 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i 9ewhdf8 hwed7uhyeu ewhdfyuh"},
   {"key": "b", "title": "DITF 2018", "details": "rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr rhgiuhs huiwghf 3ejfow fnhbviuo rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy gefgey8 egf8 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i fhgiuh hguhsi ruhgiuherih shif"},
   {"key": "a", "title": "ICC T20", "details": "rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr rhgiuhs huiwghf 3ejfow fnhbviuo rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9 gefgey8 egf8 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i 9ewhdf8 hwed7uhyeu ewhdfyuh"},
   {"key": "b", "title": "DITF 2018", "details": "rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr rhgiuhs huiwghf 3ejfow fnhbviuo rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy gefgey8 egf8 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i fhgiuh hguhsi ruhgiuherih shif"},
   {"key": "a", "title": "ICC T20", "details": "rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr rhgiuhs huiwghf 3ejfow fnhbviuo rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9 gefgey8 egf8 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i 9ewhdf8 hwed7uhyeu ewhdfyuh"},
   {"key": "b", "title": "DITF 2018", "details": "rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr rhgiuhs huiwghf 3ejfow fnhbviuo rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy gefgey8 egf8 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i fhgiuh hguhsi ruhgiuherih shif"},
   {"key": "a", "title": "ICC T20", "details": "rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr rhgiuhs huiwghf 3ejfow fnhbviuo rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9 gefgey8 egf8 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i 9ewhdf8 hwed7uhyeu ewhdfyuh"},
   {"key": "b", "title": "DITF 2018", "details": "rgybfdf enfijn efnhiueh fhiuerhngf reuigfr rhgiuhs huiwghf 3ejfow fnhbviuo rgybfdf ehf euhfiue eshfu9he eh9f9uhe ehgf9gy gefgey8 egf8 9ewgf89e 9ewghf8g 9ewhfd8i fhgiuh hguhsi ruhgiuherih shif"}
  ]
 },
 {"key": "c", "title": "Politics", "image": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mudassir21/server/master/img/politics.jpg"},
 {"key": "d", "title": "Entertainment", "image": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mudassir21/server/master/img/entertainment.png"},
 {"key": "e", "title": "Economics", "image": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mudassir21/server/master/img/economics.jpg"},
 {"key": "f", "title": "Technology", "image": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mudassir21/server/master/img/technology.jpg"},
 {"key": "g", "title": "Others", "image": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mudassir21/server/master/img/m.jpg"}
]
}
```

Now I want to load only one news array which user selects.
Here my code of loading data.

```js
componentDidMount() {
     return fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mudassir21/server/master/newsCategory.json')
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((responseJson) => {
         let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
         this.setState({
           isLoading: false,
           dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.Cat),
           dataNews: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.Cat[this.state.rowNo].news)
              }, function() {
           // do something with new state
         });
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
       });
   }
```

Here the code of view data

```js
<ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataNews}
            //dataSource={news}
            renderRow={(rowData) => 
             <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.option}
        onPress = { ()=> this.setState({ newsTitle: rowData.title, newsDetails: rowData.details })}
       >
             <Text style={styles.title}>{rowData.title}</Text>
             <Text>{rowData.details}</Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
            }
          />
```

I set the state value of rowNo 0 in the constructor. But I want to change this state variable value by clicking a button and then want to set the dataNews value with new rowNo value. In every click of a button there sets new value of rowNo so there needs to set new data in dataNews every time.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use another function for loading data and call it every click. Like this

```js
newsLoad(num) {
    this.setState({rowNo: num});
     return fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mudassir21/server/master/newsCategory.json')
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((responseJson) => {
         let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
         this.setState({
           isLoading: false,
           dataNews: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.Cat[this.state.rowNo].news)
         }, function() {
           // do something with new state
         });
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
       });
   }
```